# How to colorize specific React.Js syntax on vscode?

Tags: scope, themes, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I'm trying to figure out how to get a specific color syntax with vscode in a declaration of a class in `React`.

These are the colors I want to get:

[image]

As you see, the name of the class `StorePicker` is a *purple*, and the React method `.Component` (including the dot) is a  *pale grey*.

As far as I know, to play with color syntax on vscode, it needs to be with the `TM Scope`. So to make this, on my code file where I have the class declaration, I press `Ctrl+Shift+p` and search for `Inspect TM Scopes`, and click on the specific elements to get their respective scopes.

---

In my specific case, I got these scopes for the elements I need to colorize:

- The class Name `StorePicker` (`entity.name.class.js, source.js`)
- The `React` keyword (`entity.name.class.js, source.js`)
- The `.` (`keyword.operator.accessor.js, source.js`)
- The method `Component` (`entity.name.class.js, source.js`)

As you can see, the `StorePicker` (class name), the `React` keyword and the method `Component` share the same Scope: `entity.name.class.js`.

So let's say I want to colorize only the `.Component`. So I put this on my theme's config:

```
{
    "name": "[JAVASCRIPT] - Operator Accesor + Method",
    "scope": ["keyword.operator.accessor.js", "entity.name.class.js", "source.js"],
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#c2cacf"
    }
}
```

but `StorePicker` and `React.Component` are also colorized with the same color:

[image]

And I also want to colorize only the `StorePicker` (class name):

```
{
    "name": "[JAVASCRIPT] - Only Class Name",
    "scope": ["entity.name.class.js", "source.js"],
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#d393e9"
    }
}
```

Again not only is `StorePicker` colorized, but `React` and `Component` are colorized with the same color too:

[image]

**My question:**

How I can get them colorized separately like in the first image (taken from a Screencast), if they share the same **Scope**?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you got those scopes...

```
{
    "scope": "entity.name.type.module.js",
    "settings": { "foreground": "#e2b419" }
},
{
    "scope": "entity.other.inherited-class.js",
    "settings": { "foreground": "#c2cacf" }
},
{
    "scope": "entity.name.type.class.js",
    "settings": { "foreground": "#d393e9" }
},
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your interest on my question. On my Q, in 3rd paragraph, I explain how I did to get those scopes. Let me tell you that I have tested your answer, and does not works. The colors are the same, there are no changes. Have you tested that?

Comment: LanguageId? vscode version? Example of code that doesn't work?

Comment: javascript, 1.33.1 (user setup), `class StorePicker extends React.Component {}` I'm using the theme `Cobalt2`

Comment: Alex: why some `scopes` are inside an array, others are only separated by commas inside a strings, others are separated by spaces inside a string?

Comment: Do you have any extension that overwrites `javascript` grammar? For instance, can you try to launch vscode without extensions and see if grammar is different... `code --disable-extensions`

Comment: Space in `scope` means a descendant selector. Array or string - is just a preference of how to write multiple selectors.

Comment: Finally, an extension called `Babel JavaScript` was the problem because it highlights the js code, changing my actual theme's config. Thanks for your suggestions !!!!